# npm can't handle leading 0's in version #-- `npm version patch` not being recognized- resulting in ```npm !ERR```

Tags: git, npm, version, package.json

I am using node 7.10.1 (which has npm 4.2.0). I am running on Windows 7 SP1.

In other projects in the past, I have used the following to rev the version numbers in my package.json:

- `git add .`
- `git commit - m "reason for change"`
- `npm version patch`

This worked seamlessly in 3 other projects I have done.

Now, when I run this on my current project, I get the following error/output:

```
> npm version patch
npm ERR! npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor | preminor | prepatch | prerelease | from-git]
npm ERR! (run in package dir)
npm ERR! 'npm -v' or 'npm --version' to print npm version (4.2.0)
npm ERR! 'npm view <pkg> version' to view a package's published version
npm ERR! 'npm ls' to inspect current package/dependency versions
```

The `package.json` is working fine to do all its other tasks (build, install, etc). Despite the indication in the second line of the output shown above, I am running the command in the package directory root level (same directory as `package.json`).

Is there something in my package.json that the `npm version patch` doesn't like?  The error tells me nothing about what is wrong, let alone how to fix it. The local repo copy seems fine. I even deleted and re-cloned it thinking perhaps I had some problem locally, but no change.

All I can see clearly by this error is just `npm !ERR` and the rest of the output seems to make no sense.  The only things I have globally installed via npm are :

```
npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- electron@1.7.6
`-- gulp-cli@1.3.0
```

Below is my `package.json` in case there is something wrong in it...

```js
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.01.19",
  "description": "My Project",
  "productName": "My Project",
  "copyright": "Copyright (C) My Company, Inc. All Rights Reserved",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p --progress",
    "build:dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --display-error-details",
    "build": "rm -rf testDist && tsc",
    "start": "electron .",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "//": "test : ./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./ServerSide/test/fileHandler.test.js --reporter spec",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "posttest": "node_modules/.bin/remap-istanbul -i converage/coverage-final.json -o coverage -t html",
    "coverage": "http-server -c-1 -o -p 9875 ./coverage",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://mylocalgitserver.company.com/my-program/my-project-repo.git"
  },
  "author": "My Company",
  "authors": [
    "My Project Team"
  ],
  "os": [
    "win32"
  ],
  "cpu": [
    "ia32",
    "x64"
  ],
  "license": "",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.3.4",
    "@types/deep-diff": "0.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
    "electron": "1.7.6",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",,
    "gulp-if": "2.0.2",
    "gulp-jscs": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "2.0.4",
    "http-server": "0.10.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "less": "2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "4.0.5",
    "loader-utils": "1.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "mocha": "3.5.0",
    "remap-istanbul": "0.9.5",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "shelljs": "0.7.8",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "webpack": "3.5.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "yargs": "8.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.17.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "ejs": "2.5.7",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "fs-exists-sync": "0.1.0",
    "morgan": "1.8.2",
    "project-interface-module": "git+http:///mylocalgitserver.company.com/my-program/project-interface-module.git#v2.7.0",
    "stream-to-buffer": "0.1.0",
    "uuid": "3.1.0",
    "valid-filename": "2.0.1",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "yauzl": "2.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(posting an answer that I figured out)

The problem is that I had leading zeros in the version number field.

It turns out that the **version field in `package.json` cannot have leading zeros** in any part of it. Specifically, in my package.json, I had the following:

```
{
... ... ..
  "version": "0.01.19",
... ... ..
}
```

This is what causes this command

```
npm version patch
```

to produce the error:

```
npm ERR! npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor | preminor | prepatch | prerelease | from-git]
npm ERR! (run in package dir)
npm ERR! 'npm -v' or 'npm --version' to print npm version (4.2.0)
npm ERR! 'npm view <pkg> version' to view a package's published version
npm ERR! 'npm ls' to inspect current package/dependency versions
```

The fix is to change the version field in the package.json file to the following:

```
{
... ... ..
  "version": "0.1.19",
... ... ..
}
```

While it is good that I found the issue, `npm` is producing no helpful information when this error occurs. There is literally no way to debug what is happening by the error message produced. This should be changed by `npm`. Until then, beware of not allowing leading zeros in your package.json.